# how to get a float from a matrix in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, int, pow

let's say that I have a matrix in python like this:

```
>>> xn
matrix([[ 1.99995048],
        [ 3.99999329],
        [ 2.        ]])
```

and now I would like to get the element [2][0]
then

```
>>> z=xn[2][0]
>>> z
matrix([[ 2.]])
```

then the result is "matrix. I would like to use that number for another operation, let's say 2^z, but since z is 'matrix', I got this:

```
>>> 2**z
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'matrix'
```

How can I make that z would be just z=2 (in this case)?
Thanks in advance.
/joc

Update:
I found it!

```
>>> z=xn.tolist()[2][0]
```

Comment: Using `tolist` is inefficient.  Use `x[2, 0]`; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the many reasons you shouldn't use `matrix`. (Or at least be very aware of why you're using it if you choose to.)

Using a `numpy.matrix` forces everything to be 2D.

Also, `matrix` overloads the `**` operator to be a matrix power (e.g. `x.dot(x)` for `x**2`). Therefore, `2**x` doesn't have a meaning if `x` is a matrix.  (It does if `x` is an array!)

Just use an `numpy.array` instead of `numpy.matrix`.

In that case:

```
import numpy as np

xn = np.array([[ 1.99995048], [ 3.99999329], [ 2. ]])
z = xn[2, 0] # Or "xn[2][0]", they're equivalent.

print z
print 2**z
```

In this case, `z` is `2.0` (instead of `matrix([[2.0]])`), and `2**z` is 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

To access the element at row 2, column 0 of the matrix `xn`,  use `xn[2, 0]` (not `xn[2][0]`):

```
In [12]: xn = np.matrix([[2.0],[3.0],[1.5]])

In [13]: xn
Out[13]: 
matrix([[ 2. ],
        [ 3. ],
        [ 1.5]])

In [14]: z = xn[2, 0]

In [15]: z
Out[15]: 1.5

In [16]: type(z)
Out[16]: numpy.float64

In [17]: 2**z
Out[17]: 2.8284271247461903
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `numpy.array` as Joe suggests (for example you might need some of the special methods that are only on the matrix type), the best way to get your element out of a 1-element matrix is with the `.item` method:

```
>>> xn[0]
matrix([[ 1.99995048]])
>>> xn[0].item()
1.99995048
```

Comment: Why not simply: `xn[0,0] >>> 1.99995048` This works just fine for numpy matrices or arrays.

Comment: Good question.  The difference is in the type, `xn[0,0]` will give you a numpy type and `.item` is guaranteed to give you a pure python type.

Comment: If thats your reason you may be complicating this, `xn[0].item()` on a 2D matrix or row matrix will of course return an error. It would be more consistent with general array notation to explicitly state the index rather then relying on the caveat of 0-dimensional arrays `item()` call. I do not mean to be picky, but I think this could cause issues down the road.

Comment: *shrugs*  I was merely recommending it as an alternative to `.tolist`.  I think `xn[0,0]` is quite fine too, although `.item` does have the added advantage of ensuring that the name you _thought_ was a 1-element array actually _is_ bound to a 1-element array.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

> > > z=xn.tolist()[2][0]